# Se excede del límite del peso de subida y no se muestra en mensaje en la vista

Tags: glassfish, xhtml, richfaces

El archivo no se carga porque excede el máximo permitido, pero no muestra ningún mensaje. Estoy usando *GlassFish 3.1*.

El error que obtengo es el siguiente:

> Upload exceeds its maximum permitted size of 104857600 bytes

Este es el código del *XHTML*:

```html
<rich:fileUpload styleClass="tablaIconoTexto W127PImp"
 sizeExceededLabel="Excede el tamano"
 fileUploadListener="#{loadReceivableLetterAction.listener}"
 id="upload" immediateUpload="true" listHeight="0px"
 autoclear="true" clearAllLabel=""
 onfileselect="#{rich:component('statPane')}.show();"
 addLabel="#{message.file_label_select_file}">
 <a:ajax event="uploadcomplete" execute="@none"
  render="panelFile, messageSearchPopUp, panelLoadFile, upload, buttonLoad, messages" />
</rich:fileUpload>
<rich:message for="upload" />
```

Comment: Hola, @Mabell Boada  el error es claro, estás superando el máximo permitido, comparte tu vista y como tienes tu web.xml y en que servidor  haces deploy. Da una vuelta antes por esta liga : [mcve] y [tour]

Comment: Esto casi parece más un problema con la configuración de servidor. ¿Qué servidor usas? Creo que hay otra pregunta parecida ya en el sitio

Comment: Si, el error es claro solo que no muestra ningún mensaje de error en la vista estoy validando con algunas de las propiedades de richfaces como sizeExceededLabel, pero no hay un mensaje que le avise al usuario qué error ocurrió durante la carga.

Comment: @MabellBoada agrega tu `web.xml` donde se vea como agregaste el parámetro `maxRequestSize`  y que servidor de aplicaciones estás usando, ya que con la información que nos das no es posible reproducir el error.

Answer (score 0):

El `fileUpload` tiene un evento `onerror`

```
onerror="alert('Ups');"
```

Ya solo se agrega a la descricpcion del `fileUpload`

```
<rich:fileUpload styleClass="tablaIconoTexto W127PImp"
    onerror="mostrarError('Algo mas descriptivo');" <***************************************
    sizeExceededLabel="Excede el tamano"
    fileUploadListener="#{loadReceivableLetterAction.listener}"
    id="upload" immediateUpload="true" listHeight="0px"
    autoclear="true" clearAllLabel=""
    onfileselect="#{rich:component('statPane')}.show();"
    addLabel="#{message.file_label_select_file}">
    <a:ajax event="uploadcomplete" execute="@none"
        render="panelFile, messageSearchPopUp, panelLoadFile, upload, buttonLoad, messages" />
</rich:fileUpload>
<rich:message for="upload" />
```

De momento no recuerdo si se puede capturar el tipo de error en el evento, pero prueba, espero te ayude.

Answer (score 0):

A tu `web.xml` hace falta el parámetro `maxRequestSize` :

```
   <context-param>
        <param-name>org.richfaces.fileUpload.maxRequestSize</param-name>
        <param-value>10000000</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.richfaces.fileUpload.createTempFiles</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
```

En el sitio de rich faces te lo indica :

> FileUpload requires two context-parameter's to be set in web.xml:
>
> - createTempFiles boolean attribute which defines whether the uploaded    files are stored in temporary files or available in the
>     listener    directly as byte[] data (false for this example).
> - maxRequestSize attribute defines max size in bytes of the uploaded    files (100,000 for this example).

[web.xml](https://github.com/richfaces/richfaces/blob/master/examples/showcase/src/main/webapp-openshift/WEB-INF/web.xml)